# How to prove product rule for interior product?

Tags: exterior-algebra

At 5:16 of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BseMHDf_evQ&list=PLB8F2D70E034E9C29&index=30), the following product rule is brought up:

$$ t_u( \alpha \wedge \beta)= (t_u \alpha) \wedge \beta + (-1)^{|\alpha|} \alpha \wedge t_u \beta$$

I want to know how to prove this.

---

I thought of proving this using the same logic for the exterior derivative:

$$ d( \alpha \wedge \beta) = d \alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^{|\alpha|}\alpha \wedge d \beta$$

For a $p$ form $\alpha$ and a $q$ form $\beta$

Now the proof of this (at least one I know) proves it for $\alpha= \tilde{\alpha} dx_{i_1} \wedge dx_{i_2}...dx_{i_p}$ and $\beta=\tilde{\beta} dx_{j_1} \wedge dx_{j_2}... dx_{j_q}$ and the extends it to form fields with components along the different 'form basis' by the linearity of derivative.

I know the rule is linear, so I just need to figure out how to work it out with the a one component form.

Comment: From 3:35 to 4:00 he explains what he's about to do. At 3:50 he explains that he is going to give the three rules that define  $\iota$. You need to know (1): how it acts on basis $1$-forms, (2): how it interacts with sums and (3): how it interacts with wedges. You cannot deduce (3) from (1) and (2) only.
From 4:00 to 5:03 he explains (1) and (2). At 5:03 he starts explaining (3). I repeat, he is taking it as a definition of the $\iota$.

Comment: How does one motivate the rules then? @JackozeeHakkiuz